# Does POSIX specify that only one signal can interrupt pselect?

Tags: c, select, posix

The [POSIX `pselect` function](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pselect.html) take a signal mask argument. The signal mask is "atomically" set as the current mask before execution of the function begins, and is restored as the function returns.

This allows an otherwise masked signal to be unmasked while the function executes, and masked again when the function returns. It's guaranteed<sup>*</sup> that if a signal unmasked in this way is caught, the `pselect` function will be interrupted by the signal and (unless the signal action is specified with the `SA_RESTART` flag) will return an `EINTR` error.

(*: or is it? the language in the document linked above would seem to allow that a signal being received *between* when `pselect` unblocked due to seeing a file readiness or timeout and when it replaced the signal mask with the original would not necessarily cause `EINTR`, since `EINTR` is required if "The function was interrupted while blocked ..." - however, that ultimately doesn't affect this question).

My question is: supposing that two separate signals are temporarily unmasked during `pselect` execution, is it possible that both signals will be caught before the `pselect` function returns and the previous signal mask is restored - or is there some kind of guarantee that only one signal will be caught in this case (leaving the other one pending)? (For purposes of the question, suppose that `SA_RESTART` is not set for the signal action, and that all signals were specified to be masked during execution of the signal handler when it was established via `sigaction`).

I can find nothing which suggests that only one signal may be processed, but I may have missed something, and I am writing some code for which this would be a very useful guarantee. I'd be interested to know if POSIX itself makes any guarantee, and also if different OSes provide such a guarantee independently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've continued searching and found no additional information, so I can only conclude that there are no guarantees in POSIX generally.

Under Linux, if I understand the code below correctly, only one signal can be handled (assuming that the signal handler itself doesn't unmask signals): the relevant code and a revealing comment is in fs/select.c, in the `do_pselect` function:

```
ret = core_sys_select(n, inp, outp, exp, to);
ret = poll_select_copy_remaining(&end_time, tsp, 0, ret);

if (ret == -ERESTARTNOHAND) {
    /*
     * Don't restore the signal mask yet. Let do_signal() deliver
     * the signal on the way back to userspace, before the signal
     * mask is restored.
     */
    if (sigmask) {
        memcpy(&current->saved_sigmask, &sigsaved,
                sizeof(sigsaved));
        set_restore_sigmask();
    }
} else ...
```

It essentially returns from the system call, allowing the signal handler to execute, after which the original signal mask will immediately be restored (from `current->saved_sigmask`, because `set_restore_sigmask()` sets a flag indicating that this should occur).

The following test program verifies this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/select.h>

volatile sig_atomic_t got_usr1 = 0;
volatile sig_atomic_t got_usr2 = 0;

void handle_usr1(int signo, siginfo_t *info, void *v)
{
  got_usr1 = 1;
}

void handle_usr2(int signo, siginfo_t *info, void *v)
{
  got_usr2 = 1;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  // mask SIGUSR1 and SIGUSR2:
  sigset_t curmask;
  sigemptyset(&curmask);
  sigaddset(&curmask, SIGUSR1);
  sigaddset(&curmask, SIGUSR2);
  sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &curmask, NULL);

  // Create a mask for all but SIGUSR1 and SIGUSR2:
  sigset_t mask;
  sigfillset(&mask);
  sigdelset(&mask, SIGUSR1);
  sigdelset(&mask, SIGUSR2);

  // Set up signal handlers:
  struct sigaction action;
  action.sa_sigaction = handle_usr1;
  sigfillset(&action.sa_mask);
  action.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
  sigaction(SIGUSR1, &action, NULL);

  action.sa_sigaction = handle_usr2;
  sigaction(SIGUSR2, &action, NULL);

  // Make signals pending:
  raise(SIGUSR1);
  raise(SIGUSR2);

  // pselect with no file descriptors and no timeout:
  pselect(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, &mask);

  int count = got_usr1 + got_usr2;

  printf("Handled %d signals while in pselect.\n", count);
  return 0;
}
```

On Linux, the output of the above is consistently:

> Handled 1 signals while in pselect.

This also seems to be the case on FreeBSD; however, I'm not willing to count on this being the case on all other platforms. The solution I have found to ensuring that only one signal can be handled is to use `siglongjmp` to jump out of the signal handler as well as out of the `pselect` call while also restoring the signal mask so that no further signals can be processed.

Essentially, that code looks like this:

```
    jmp_buf jbuf; // signal handlers have access to this

    if (sigsetjmp(jbuf, 1) != 0) {
        // We received a signal while in pselect ...
    }

    int r = pselect(nfds, &read_set_c, &write_set_c, &err_set, wait_ts, &sigmask);
```

The signal handlers must execute a `siglongjmp`:

```
void signal_handler(int signo, siginfo_t *siginfo, void *v)
{
    siglongjmp(jbuf, 1);
}
```

This feels crufty, but seems to work on all platforms that I've tested it on (Linux, MacOS and FreeBSD) - furthermore it seems to be supported by POSIX generally.

Answer (score 1):

No, but it also doesn’t specify that multiple signals can or must.  Since it is unspecified, it is best to follow the general rule, which allows all pending unmasked signals to be processed.  If you attempt to strictly depend upon this, you are likely on a bad path because the timing of asynchronous events is difficult to predict.

In general, it would be very difficult to make an implementation that imposed an ‘only one' restriction because the os runtime would have to leave one or more signals pending but unmasked until some unspecified point.  Remember that the signal handler which runs when pselect is interrupted could do a siglongjmp rather than returning, so the kernel would have to keep a complicated, possibly unbounded data structure to track which signal mask to enforce.

Below is a modified version of your test program.   In this one, each event emits a string via write() so there are no buffering problems.  The program sets its “main” environment to mask SIGUSR1, SIGUSR2; but while pselect is running, it permits SIGUSR1, SIGUSR2, SIGTERM.
The program forks, with the parent (default:) sitting in a loop invoking pselect(), then outputting ‘.’ after it completes.
The child sits in a loop, delivering SIGUSR1, SIGUSR2 to the parent, then sleeping for a bit.  It outputs ‘^’ after delivering the signals.
The handler emits a prefix “(1” or “(2” for SIGUSR1, SIGUSR2 resp; then sleeps for a bit, and outputs “)” to indicate the sleep has completed.

The output I see on macos (10.12.6, but I doubt it matters much) is:
^(2)(1).^(2)(1).^(2)(1).^(2)(1).Terminated: 15
which indicates that the signal handler for each of SIGUSR1 and SIGUSR2 are being run for every invocation of pselect().   This is what I would expect; as it is designed to not admit a window of uncertainty as would be the case with bracketting select() with sigprocmasks().

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void handle(int signo)
{
    char s[2];
    s[0] = '(';
    s[1] = signo == SIGUSR1? '1' : '2';
    write(1, s, 2);
    sleep(1);
    write(1, ")", 1);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  sigset_t mask;
  sigemptyset(&mask);
  sigaddset(&mask, SIGUSR1);
  sigaddset(&mask, SIGUSR2);
  sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &mask, NULL);

  sigfillset(&mask);
  sigdelset(&mask, SIGUSR1);
  sigdelset(&mask, SIGUSR2);
  sigdelset(&mask, SIGTERM);
  signal(SIGUSR1, handle);
  signal(SIGUSR2, handle);
  pid_t t = fork();
  switch (t) {
  default:
    while (1) {
            /* no USR1, USR2 */
            pselect(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, &mask);
            /* no USR1, USR2 */
            write(1, ".", 1);
    }
    break;
  case 0:
    t = getppid();
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        kill(t, SIGUSR1);
        kill(t, SIGUSR2);
        write(1, "^", 1);
        sleep(5);
    }
    kill(t, SIGTERM);
    break;
  case -1:
    perror("fork\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have come to a similar conclusion, but I don't follow your logic about the difficulty of having an "only one" restriction, since if a handled signal executes a `siglongjmp` then that definitely precludes other signals being received while pselect is executing (i.e. this manually enforces the "only one restriction"). And in fact, this is the solution I ended up using to ensure that I detected only one signal while in `pselect`. Code here, if you're interested: https://github.com/davmac314/dasynq/blob/master/dasynq-pselect.h

Comment: Inside pselect, it would have to choose which signal to permit, and which to wait until sometime later to permit, and because there is no guarantee that the signal handler will return (siglongjmp), it needs to store that decision somewhere, so it can eventually run the handler for it.  This amounts to an “up” call, even though you wouldn’t implement it as such, every other call would then have to check whether it was time to run that handler or not.

Comment: Now, suppose that in that original handler, I invoked pselect again, directly, with an adjusted mask, and the same thing happened (two awakening signals), and again the kernel makes a decision about which one to permit, it now has to store the next one.

Comment: As I dig myself in deeper, I recycle the mask of two of the previously occurred but not delivered signals, again the kernel has to choose one, and store the other.

Comment: See also my own answer, where I've included a test program showing that on Linux, only one signal is handled during `pselect` even though two are pending. This contradicts what you are saying.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166777/discussion-between-mevets-and-davmac).

Comment: As noted in chat, your example uses `signal` instead of `sigaction` to establish handlers and therefore doesn't mask other signals during handler execution. This was a key part of the question - _For purposes of the question, suppose that SA_RESTART is not set for the signal action, and that all signals were specified to be masked during execution of the signal handler when it was established via sigaction_ - if you don't do that then one signal can interrupt another's handler.

Comment: Yes, sorry, hadn’t read your question properly.   The ‘main’ signal mask will be the one in force when the signal handler has returned.   I thought you were suggesting something quite different.